# Regex for Name Only in UITextfield

Tags: ios, regex, xcode, uitextfield

I create below code for Regex for name that contain Alphabets  only

```
For Eg:
John -Correct
John123-Incorrect
John 123 - Incorrect
John Micheal -it shows incorrect as its have whitespace . How to fix it?



 -(BOOL)validateNameWithString:(NSString*)nameStr
    {
        NSString *nameRegex = @"^[a-zA-Z]*$";

        NSPredicate *testRegex = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", nameRegex];
        if(![testRegex evaluateWithObject:nameStr])
            return NO;
        else
            return YES;

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the whitespace token `\s` to the list of allowed tokens:

```
^[a-zA-Z\s]*$
```

check this [working on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/HIstfR/1)

And as pointed out in the comments, you need to escape the backslash

```
NSString *nameRegex =@"^[a-zA-Z\\s]*$";
```

Comment: unknown escape sequence \s warning

Comment: NSString *nameRegex =@"^[a-zA-Z\\s]*$";
 fix it thanks