# jquery validation number error

Tags: jquery, validation, keydown

i want to validate a input using `jQuery` it must accept only alphabets the code is working numbers in keyboard are not allowed but numpad numbers are typing what can do with this

```
$("#fname").keydown(function(event) {
   var keyentered = event.keyCode || event.which;
   keyentered = String.fromCharCode(keyentered);
   var pattern = /[a-zA-Z]+|[\b]+$/;
   if(!pattern.test(keyentered)){
     event.returnValue = false;
     if(event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();
   }
});
```

this is my code it must not accept any special char and numbers but it is accepting numbers from numpad and not accept number which is in keyboard above alphabets i want know why and how to resolve this.

Need Help!

Comment: Potential duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40362688/regex-for-name-only-in-uitextfield

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine. below code will only allow alphabet to enter in textbox using jQuery.

```
$("#fname").keydown(function (e) {
    // Allow backspace, delete, 
    // Allow select all the alphabet entered in textbox using Ctrl+A or Command+A
    // Allow: home, end, left, right, down and up to navigate in textbox if any changes want to do
    if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, [8, 46]) !== -1 ||
            (e.keyCode === 65 && (e.ctrlKey === true || e.metaKey === true)) ||
            (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 40)) {
        return;
    }
    // Below code is to only allow alphabet and stop propogation on entering other char
    if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 65 || e.keyCode > 90)) && (e.keyCode < 65 || e.keyCode > 90)) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: sure.. its worked for me.. thats why i said thank you... thank you so much once again..@TechnoCrat